# Javascript timeout loop to save multiple rows to Parse.com

Tags: javascript, json, loops, parse-platform, timeout

I have written a `beforeSave` script in parse.com cloud code. I would like to save all my results to parse so they are all run through this script and their data is modified before saving.

I have tacked this in the following way.

1. Exported JSON from Parse.com dashboard.
2. use this as a local JSON in my app and run the following loop:

CODE:

```
$http.get('data/full_data.json')
   .then(function(res) {
  var counter = 0;
      for (var i = 0; i < res.data.results.length; i++) {
          setDelay(counter);
          saveToParse(res.data.results[i]);
          counter ++
      };
    }
  });

function setDelay(i) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log(i);
  }, 1000);
}

function saveToParse(exercise) {

  console.log(exercise);
  ParseFactory.provider('Exercises/').edit(exercise.objectId, exercise).success(function(data) {

  }).error(function(response) {
    $ionicLoading.hide();
    $rootScope.$emit('errorEvent', {
      "message": "Please check your connection",
      "errorObject": response
    });
  });
}
```

I have been trying to have a timeout function so I do not exceed the number of API calls allowed on Parse.com.

My problem is that all my API calls are done and then it run the timeouts really quickly at the end after a 1 second pause.

How can I ensure each loop iteration takes a timeout before looping again.

---

The answers work perfectly for the first 50 seconds and then work slowly... see this screen grab of the network activity.

[image: network trace]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make all your functions return promises. And to make the loop async you convert it into a recursive "loop".

```
$http.get('data/full_data.json')
     .then(function(res) {
       function loop(i) {
         if(i < res.data.results.length) {
           return saveToParse(res.data.results[i]).then(function() {
             return delay(100);
           }).then(function() {
             return loop(i + 1);
           });
         }
         else return Promise.resolve(res);
       };
       return loop(0);
     }).then(function(res) {
       console.log("finished saving");
     });



function delay(time) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(resolve, time);
  });
}

function saveToParse(exercise) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    console.log(exercise);
    ParseFactory.provider('Exercises/').edit(exercise.objectId, exercise)
      .success(resolve).error(function(response) {
        var error = {
          "message": "Please check your connection",
          "errorObject": response
        };
        reject(error);
        $ionicLoading.hide();
        $rootScope.$emit('errorEvent', error);
      });
  });
}
```

**edit:**
However it might be better to do it this way. It has the advantage of returning a promise so you can keep chaining your promises.

```
$http.get('data/full_data.json')
     .then(function(res) {
       var p = Promise.resolve();
       res.data.results.forEach(function(elem) {
         p = p.then(function() {
           return saveToParse(elem).then(function() {
             return delay(100);
           });
         });
       });
       return p;
     });
```

**edit2:**
Yet another solution to generalize async loops.

```
function asyncWhile(cond, body) {
  if(cond()) {
    return body().then(function() {
      return asyncWhile(cond, body);
    });
  } else {
    return Promise.resolve();
  }
}

function asyncFor(start, end, body) {
  var i = start;
  return asyncWhile(function() {return i < end}, function() {
    return body(i++);
  });
}

$http.get('data/full_data.json')
     .then(function(res) {
       return asyncFor(0, res.data.results.length, function(i) {
         return saveToParse(res.data.results[i]).then(function() {
           return delay(100);
         });
       }).then(function() {
         return res;
       });
     }).then(function(res) {
       console.log("finished saving");
     });
```

Comment: Works beautifully...Think I can afford to speed it up a little... taking ages... Thanks for taking the time to do this for me. Saved me a lot of time, errors and money probably!

Comment: No problem. btw. I made another edit to my first solution. I now think using a recursive loop is the best solution since it handles very long lists better (more memory efficient) but I changed it to return a promise as well.

Comment: I have had the first running for 30 minutes now - should I let it finish (1000 more) to use your new solution?

Comment: If it's too slow you can just reduce the time e.g. from 100 to 10. Also I added one more solution that might help to do asynchronous loops with promises more easily.

Comment: Sorry, there was an error in there. I can't use a normal for loop in conjunction with closures since there is only one variable i that all the closures capture. I fixed it.

Comment: Hi, is it possible to have a quick look at the edited question?

Comment: What happens if you run the whole code locally i.e. have the saveToParse function post the result to a local server? Or have it do nothing at all. Just see how much you can remove before the error disappears.

Comment: So I kinda gave this up as a bad job. I ran the loop to save to $localStorage and then imported it as JSON into parse.com :)